# HTTPS webservice with PHP session

Tags: php, ios, web-services

I need to build a WebService In PHP that using HTTPS and PHP Session.
How can i get the service from iOS (Objective c) and how to save/use the session of the php when i login to the server?

Answer (score 0):

For the PHP session, it is generally exchanged between the server and the client using cookies. So you have nothing to do as cookies are handled in the HTTP headers by the system automatically. (see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Concepts/URLOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001834-157091)).

*Note: to be sure cookies are accepted by your app (and not disabled), you may force the cookies accept policy to "Always", using `[[NSHTTPCookiesStorage sharedHTTPCookiesStorage] setCookieAcceptPolicy:NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways]`.*

---

To query your WebService then, simply use Apple's `NSURLConnection` class to send requests to it.

Or you can use some third-party frameworks that will make your life easier, building requests for you and all, like the [famous `AFNetworking` framework](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking), or if you plan to implement a RESTful WebService on your PHP server, you can also give a try to [`RESTKit`](http://restkit.org/).

Comment: Every NSURLConnection open new connection and the cookies not saved. How Can i save the cookie and send it each time i using the web-service aging?

Comment: Check that your server is correctly configured (for example use Safari to request a URL from your WebService twice and see if the cookie and session are conserved between the two connections). Also use `[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookieAcceptPolicy: NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways]` to be sure the current policy is set to accept cookies.

Comment: But i using NSURLConnection.

Comment: And? `NSURLConnection` works with `NSHTTPCookieStorage` under the hood, so I don't understand how it would be a problem, on the contrary?!

Comment: Note: maybe you should [read the dedicated Programming Guide about URL Loading on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Concepts/URLOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001834-BAJEAIEE) if you don't know about this to understand how all of this work together