# soap in ios requires cookies to be enabled. How to add it in soap header?

Tags: ios, authentication, soap

I have this webservice (.asmx) and this obj-c code (generated from wsdl2code.com)
All working fine - can connect and all that, but I need to set some extra header information into the soap calls.

In .net I only can use the service if I set the 'AllowCookies' flag WCF-config to true.

Like this:

```
var session = new WebServiceSoapClient();
     ((BasicHttpBinding)session.Endpoint.Binding).AllowCookies = true;
```

If I just used the service directly it would throw a 'user not authenticated' exception.

**Now,** Im having this problem again on iOS platform, and I don't know how/where to add the information. I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548949/https-webservice-with-php-session) and thought I could use it to do like the same trick, with just overriding a setting. No success.

Anyone got a solution?  Or information about which header to set?

(I get a token back from the first authentication, which I guess should be used here..)

UPDATE:

I opened up communication with an asp.net webapp and the webservice, and used Fiddler2 to investigate the header. It wasn't clear to me at first, because the 'Cookie'-header only contained the default auth-string in asp.net: "ASP.NET_SessionId={xxxxxxxxxxxxx}". But I only used the actual value and not not *whole* string. I guess this was a lack of basic HTTP header knowledge... I appended the whole string to a header 'Cookie' in all future requests, and it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:

I opened up communication with an asp.net webapp and the webservice, and used Fiddler2 to investigate the header. It wasn't clear to me at first, because the 'Cookie'-header only contained the default auth-string in asp.net: "ASP.NET_SessionId={xxxxxxxxxxxxx}". But I only used the actual value and not not whole string. I guess this was a lack of basic HTTP header knowledge... I appended the whole string to a header 'Cookie' in all future requests, and it worked!